# Foreach loop inside a php class?

Tags: php, arrays, class, function, foreach

I have a very simple task yet it keeps failing.

I want to have a function inside a class and the param that you pass into the function will be an array. All the function has to do is echo back the contents of the array.

Echoing out all the variables in for example the $_POST array is very easy to achieve with a foreach loop. However, it does not work in my class.

This was a very generic explanation. I you need more details please ask.

```
public function check_if_filled($array){ 
    foreach($array as $key->$value){ 
        echo $key . " : " . $value;
    } 
}
```

any advice why it gives me this error

Notice: Undefined variable: value in (my page) on line 117

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in (my page) on line 117

Comment: Please post the class code that isn't working.  Seeing the code is always easier then hearing the description of it.

Comment: Code, please. There's probably a trivial reason why the foreach is failing, and we need to see code to figure that out.

Comment: public function check_if_filled($array){
  foreach($array as $key->$value){
  } 
 }

Comment: This is a very generic comment. A very generic answer is to post your code, and a generic action will be to vote to close this question

Comment: how do I post code with the formating

Comment: so you're not actually echoing anything out in the loop??

Comment: @Tom 4 spaces indentation. I took care of it for you this time.

Comment: I'm going to assume you have a mistype with $key -> $value... $key => $value mainly because I believe it would throw an error.

Answer (score 3):

You used the wrong type of arrow in the foreach loop.

```
foreach($array as $key->$value)
```

should be

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
```

Comment: It's not an arrow, it's a hash rocket, Rocket.

Comment: @Rafe: What's a hash rocket?  `=>` is called `T_DOUBLE_ARROW` according to PHP.  http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php

Comment: @Rafe: `->` is called the `arrow operator` in all languages.

Comment: @Rocket I call it the member dereference operator in C, and I don't think I've ever referred to it by name in PHP. Hash rocket is what Ruby programmers call it, which is funny in itself, plus your name *is* Rocket, so...

Comment: @Rafe: I've never heard it called a hash rocket. :-P